# Prevent leading and trailing commas using group() & agg() statements in a large DataFrame, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large DataFrame I'm working where I need to groupby() by one of the ID columns and place everything else in a csv list.  I've got one approach that also utlizes the agg() method that works well.
However, I'm noticing in the case where I have an empty (null) value in a cell, this approach will preserve the empty (null) with a leading or trailing commas.  I need to prevent that.

Replacing each column one at a time with either .lstrip(',') or .rstrip(',') is probably out of the question due to the nature of the DataFrame.  I also need to preserve the empty (null) in the source data, so I can't go back and auto fill in a dummy value.

What it looks like...

[image]

What I need...

[image]

```
# Needed Libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Sample Dataset
columnsNames = ["IDColumn", "ColB", "ColC"]
valuesList = [["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "", "c"], ["a", "b", ""]]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columnsNames, data=valuesList)

# groupby() & agg() statement 
df = df.groupby(['IDColumn']).agg(lambda x: ','.join([str(elem) for elem in (list(set(x)))])).replace(np.nan, "").reset_index()
df
```

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option via `applymap`:

```
df = df.groupby('IDColumn').agg(set).applymap(lambda x: ', '.join(j for j in x if j!=''))
```

Comment: Adding a 'if j!='' was the simplest solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

REPALCE the comma for the join with a space

```
# Needed Libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Sample Dataset
columnsNames = ["IDColumn", "ColB", "ColC"]
valuesList = [["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "", "c"], ["a", "b", ""]]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columnsNames, data=valuesList)

# groupby() & agg() statement 
df = df.groupby(['IDColumn']).agg(lambda x: ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in (list(set(x)))])).replace(np.nan, "").reset_index()
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a boolean index to filter out empty strings + [`unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html#pandas-series-unique) + [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
import pandas as pd

columnsNames = ["IDColumn", "ColB", "ColC"]
valuesList = [["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "", "c"], ["a", "b", ""]]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columnsNames, data=valuesList)

result = df.groupby('IDColumn', as_index=False)[['ColB', 'ColC']].agg(
    lambda s: ','.join(s[s.ne('')].unique())
)

print(result)
```

`result`:

```
  IDColumn ColB ColC
0        a    b    c
```